# PowerShell SQL Server Processor Performance Counter

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'd like to monitor the Processor-Load on a Server with 8 SQL Instances.
I discover the proper counters with:

```
get-counter -listset processor | select -expandproperty counter
```

I get something like: \Processor(*)% Processor Time and \Process(sqlsrv#1...sqlsrv#XX) which I'm intersting in.
I can now declare my counter:

```
$counter="\Process(sqlsrv#1)\% Processor Time"; Get-counter -counter $counter -sampleInterval 3
```

But how do I know which one of the SQL-Instances is hidden behind "sqlsrv#1".."sqlsrv#8"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't think we have direct way to do that... But

Says suppose - If you have 3 Instance in your Server (Process will be **sqlservr**, **sqlservr#1** and **sqlservr#2**). Right ?

You can find the PID of each of them using below Counter name **ID Process** in Process Object

```
\Process(sqlservr)\ID Process
\Process(sqlservr#1)\ID Process
\Process(sqlservr#2)\ID Process
```

Powershell

```
Get-counter -counter "\Process(sqlservr)\ID Process"
Get-counter -counter "\Process(sqlservr#1)\ID Process"
Get-counter -counter "\Process(sqlservr#2)\ID Process"
```

Once you get the PID, You can compare the PID in Task Manager and find the "User name" tab will have the actual Instance name

**Note**: The Numbers suffixed with process called **InstanceIndex**

Comment: This might help correlate the counter process id with the running SQL instances programmatically: `$sqlInstances = & tasklist /SVC /FI "IMAGENAME eq sqlservr.exe" /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select PID, Services`. The user name alone may not be unique.